# Meteor Host multiple apps on one process (common code base)

Tags: meteor

I have very similar apps (90% shared code). I currently have different templates for each app and direct users to different entrypoints depending on the url.

The problem is that users of app A also get all the templates of APP B served in the .js bundle. This is not a problem if I have 3 apps with 90% common code and then 10% overload per app for the individual templates. However, it will become an issue in the long run.

I would normally just run individual meteor instances for each app to keep the bundle small, but this makes it harder to sync the common 90% codebase.

Any best practice for my situation?

Comment: Why don't you factor out the common code into a dependency?

Comment: I'm not sure how easy/practical that would be for my case. The common code includes most meteor components (methods, routes, some 100 packages, collection schemas, templates, css, etc.)

Comment: Then... go and find out?

Answer (score 0):

While I would suggest using the package system as well, the OP has stated he doesn't want to go that route.  One possible alternative would be using Git's submodule system for the common code:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Basically, you have a git repo that has all the common code and acts as a dependent module of your top-level repos with the differing code.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to create package for your `shared code`

Good source to create package:

1. https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/writing-a-package/
2. https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-write-a-package-for-meteor-js-e5534c6bd3c2#.67eeiu59s

After you publish your shared code as package, you can install them to any of your app. Then, you can use your shared code not only on your App A or B, but as much app as you want.